# Jquery Drag and Drop - adding existing option to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created timetables, where user (student or teacher) can drag his subject and drop to own choice cell. Everything works, but I absolutely don't know, how can I do deleting subjects from timetable, but not for dropped item, but for loading subjects after refreshing website.

The code is too long, so I saved it to JSFiddle.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("connecting-to-database.php");

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `timetables` WHERE `who` = :username");
$query->execute(array(
":username" => $_SESSION["id"]["username"]));

$timetable = $query->fetch();

if($timetable) {
    $now_timetable = $timetable["day"];
} else {
    $now_timetable = "nothing";
}

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `subjects`");
$query->execute();
$subjects = $query->fetchAll();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Timetable</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <h1>Timetable</h1>

    <div class="timetable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>1<br>(8:00 - 8:45)</th>
                <th>2<br>(8:50 - 9:35)</th>
                <th>3<br>(9:45 - 10:30)</th>
                <th>4<br>(10:50 - 11:35)</th>
                <th>5<br>(11:40 - 12:25)</th>
                <th>6<br>(12:30 - 13:15)</th>
                <th>7<br>(13:20 - 14:05)</th>
                <th>8<br>(14:10 - 14:55)</th>
                <th>9<br>(15:00 - 15:45)</th>
                <th>10<br>(15:50 - 16:35)</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <td class="drop" id="1-1"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-2"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-3"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-4"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-5"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-6"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-7"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-8"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-9"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="1-10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>T</th>
                <td class="drop" id="2-1"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-2"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-3"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-4"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-5"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-6"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-7"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-8"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-9"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="2-10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <td class="drop" id="3-1"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-2"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-3"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-4"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-5"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-6"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-7"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-8"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-9"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="3-10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>T</th>
                <td class="drop" id="4-1"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-2"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-3"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-4"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-5"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-6"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-7"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-8"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-9"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="4-10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <td class="drop" id="5-1"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-2"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-3"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-4"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-5"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-6"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-7"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-8"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-9"></td>
                <td class="drop" id="5-10"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="subjects">
        <br><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="item">Lunch</th>

                <?php
                    foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
                    ?>
                        <th class="item"><?php echo($subject["name"]); ?></th>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br><br>

        <table>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()" style="font-size: 20px; padding: 10px 20px;">
    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="location.href = 'home.php';" style="font-size: 20px; padding: 10px 20px;">

    <style type="text/css">
        .timetable table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .timetable th, td {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .item {
            text-align: center;
            width: 150px;
            height: 35px;
        }
        .assigned{
            border: 1px solid #BC2A4D;
        }
        .delete {
            background-color: red;
        }

    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
            function save() {
            var body = document.getElementById("body");
            var timetable = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                timetable[i] = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
                {
                    var el = document.getElementById((i+1) + "-" + (j+1));
                    var val = "";
                    if(el.children.length > 0)
                    {
                        val = el.firstChild.innerHTML;
                    }
                    timetable[i][j] = val;
                }
            }

            var rocket = JSON.stringify(timetable);

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", encodeURI("modify-timetable.php?timetable=" + rocket), true);
            xhttp.send();
        }

        function show(json)
        {
            var timetable = JSON.parse(json);

            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
                {
                    var val = timetable[i][j];
                    if(val.length > 0)
                    {
                        var el = document.getElementById((i+1) + "-" + (j+1));
                        var bs = document.createElement("th");
                        bs.classList.add("item");
                        bs.innerHTML = val;
                        el.appendChild(bs);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var json_timetable = '<?php echo $now_timetable; ?>';
        if(json_timetable == "nothing") {
        } else {
            show(json_timetable);
        }

        $(function(){
            $('.timetable .item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone'
            });

            $('.subjects .item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone'
            });
            $('.timetable td.drop').droppable({
                onDrop: function(e,source) {
                    if ($(source).hasClass('assigned')){
                        $(this).empty().append(source);
                    } else {
                        var c = $(source).clone().addClass('assigned');
                        $(this).empty().append(c);
                        c.draggable({
                            revert:true
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            $('.subjects').droppable({
                accept:'.assigned',

                onDragEnter: function(e, source){
                    $(source).addClass('delete');
                },
                onDragLeave: function(e, source){
                    $(source).removeClass('delete');
                },
                onDrop: function(e, source){
                    $(source).remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: put the JSFiddle link